# Attempting to free address that was not malloced , error on realloc

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, realloc

Question : https://leetcode.com/problems/find-and-replace-in-string/

"""

char * findReplaceString(char * s, int* indices, int indicesSize, char ** sources, int
sourcesSize, char ** targets, int targetsSize){

```
int len = strlen(s);
char *copyS;
char *copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
memcpy(copy, s, sizeof(char)*len);
copyS = copy;
int x = indicesSize-1;
int indexArr[1001] = {0};
int y;

for(int j=0; j<indicesSize; j++)
{
    indexArr[indices[j]] = j;
}

qsort(indices, indicesSize, sizeof(int), cmp);

while((x >= 0))
{
    y = indexArr[indices[x]];
    copy = copyS+(indices[x]);
    if(!(strncmp(copy, sources[y], strlen(sources[y]))))
    {
        copy = (char *)realloc(copy, sizeof(char)*(sizeof(copy) + sizeof(targets[y])));
        strcpy(copy, targets[y]);
    }
        
    x--;
}
return copyS;
```

}

I am getting a runtime error due to the use of realloc. I was trying to modify the input string 's'. Got a runtime error due to realloc: Trying to free memory that was not malloced.
So I malloced new string pointer , *copy. Still getting same error when  I use realloc on copy

Comment: You seem to be trying to `realloc` the value of `copy`, after you've changed the value of `copy` to not contain the original pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code.

For starters it is unclear whether the dynamically allocated array pointed to by the pointer `copy` shall contain a string or not.

If it shall contain a string then instead of

```
char *copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
memcpy(copy, s, sizeof(char)*len);
```

you need to write

```
char *copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*( len + 1 ));
memcpy(copy, s, sizeof(char)*( len + 1 ));
```

Also it is unclear why there is used the magic number `1001` in this declaration

```
int indexArr[1001] = {0};
```

The pointer `copyS` was assigned with the address of the initially allocated memory

```
char *copyS;
char *copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
memcpy(copy, s, sizeof(char)*len);
copyS = copy;
```

but then you are trying to reallocate the memory

```
copy = (char *)realloc(copy, sizeof(char)*(sizeof(copy) + sizeof(targets[y])));
```

As a result the pointer `copyS` can have an invalid value. And this pointer with an invalid value is returned from the function

```
return copyS
```

In turn the pointer `copy` is changed within the while loop

```
while((x >= 0))
{
    y = indexArr[indices[x]];
    copy = copyS+(indices[x]);
    //..
```

So after such an assignment it does not point to the previously allocated memory extent. Hence using the pointer in the call of `realloc`

```
copy = (char *)realloc(copy, sizeof(char)*(sizeof(copy) + sizeof(targets[y])));
```

invokes undefined behavior.

And again this statement

```
    copy = copyS+(indices[x]);
```

also invokes undefined behavior because after the memory reallocation the pointer `copyS` can be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do this

```
copy = copyS+(indices[x]);
```

you can no longer use 'copy' as an argument to `realloc` or `free`. The pointer you pass to these functions must be the value returned by a prior `malloc` or `realloc` (or `calloc`)

Save the original 'copy' in a variable like 'originalCopy'